# making Union for three different entities that implements the same interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have 3 entities: RatedPrice, DailyPrice and UtilizePrice.
Each entity has Code member.

I would like to write a lambda query that returns IQueryable of the three sorted by Code member. I know I need to use somewhere in Union but I don't know how.
Moreover, all the 3 entities has diffrences but are implements IPrice.

How can I do the query?

Comment: have mapped your classes as a hierarchy using EF? then EF will take care of joining

Comment: check this article http://prashantbrall.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/ef-code-first-table-per-type/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use something like this:

```
var data = ctx.RatedPrices.Select(p => new { p.Code, p.Price })
              .Concat(ctx.DailyPrices.Select(p => new { p.Code, p.Price })
                         .Contact(ctx.UtilizePrices.Select(p => new { p.Code, p.Price }))
              .OrderBy(p => p.Code);
```

Entity framework and linq-to-entities don't know what is the interface. You must use projection to some not mapped type (anonymous in the example) and deal with the result. Because you don't use entity inheritance from some base `Price` (otherwise you would not need this) you cannot expect that EF will return you instances of `RetedPrice`, `DailyPrice` and `UtilizePrice` in single result set.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

```
var list = listRatedPrice.Cast<IPrice>()
.Concat(listDailyPrice.Cast<IPrice>()
.Concat(listUtilizePrice.Cast<IPrice>))).Orderby(p => p.Code);
```

Comment: Does it return IQueryable? I can't let the concat to be on the .Net since there are a lot of elements in each type.

Comment: well, I dont think so, there is no concept of interfaces in SQL. You would have to select the columns you want from each table (like Name, price, Code...) and than concat them.

Comment: Also if you are going to get all the items to code after the sort, it wouldnt matter if you did the sort in code or in SQL server.

Comment: This is cause an exception since IPrice is not entity.